# No routes matched location "/" react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm getting this message in the console, i tried to add the index property on the element but no render the element.
The problem is in the journalRoutes but i don't see the problem.

JournalRoutes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { JournalPage } from '../pages/JournalPage'

export const JournalRoutes = () => {
  return (
   <Routes>
    <Route path="/" index element={<JournalPage/>}/>
    <Route path='*' element={<JournalPage/>}/>
   </Routes>
  )
}
```

AppRouter.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import {AuthRoutes} from "../auth/routes/AuthRoutes"
import { JournalRoutes } from '../journal/routes/JournalRoutes'
export const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/auth/*' element={<AuthRoutes/>}/>
        <Route path='/journal' element={<JournalRoutes/>}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

JournalApp.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRouter } from "./router/AppRouter";
import { AppTheme } from "./theme/AppTheme";

export const JournalApp = () => {
  return (
    <AppTheme>
      <AppRouter/>
    </AppTheme>
  );
};
```

Main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { JournalApp } from './JournalApp'
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <JournalApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: What url are you visiting when you see the console error? Currently you aren't handling "/" anywhere, so I would expect the error when visiting the root url. You only use the journal routes in /journal, so it doesn't make sense that with my /journal you handle "/" as that would never happen.

Comment: `<Route path="/" index element={<JournalPage/>}/>`
I don't think you should supply both a path and index prop on a route. An index route makes it so that it shares the path of the parent route.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `AppRouter` rendering the root `Routes` component. It isn't rendering any `"/"` path. The `"/"` route path in `JournalRoutes` is built relative from the `"/journal"` route path of the `Route` rendering `JournalRoutes`.

You just need to render a route on `"/"` in App. It can render anything, including a redirect to `"/journal"` is that is what you consider to be the "home page".

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthRoutes } from "../auth/routes/AuthRoutes";
import { JournalRoutes } from '../journal/routes/JournalRoutes';

export const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/auth/*' element={<AuthRoutes />} />
      <Route path='/journal/*' element={<JournalRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/journal" />} /> // <-- path "/"
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Additionally, while both `path` and `index` are optional props, you don't generally want to specify both at the same time. Remove one or the other.

Exmaple:

```
export const JournalRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<JournalPage />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<JournalPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

or

```
export const JournalRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={<JournalPage />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<JournalPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can git rid of the JournalRoutes  and do this in your AppRouter instead

```
 <Routes>
    <Route path='/auth/*' element={<AuthRoutes/>}/>
    <Route path='/journal'>
         <Route index element={<JournalRoutes/>}/>
         // this will route to /journal/sample but you should use Outlet to show nested routes in v6
         <Route path='sample' element={<Sample/>}/>
         <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>}/>
     </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could organise your routes something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import {AuthRoutes} from "../auth/routes/AuthRoutes"
import { JournalRoutes } from '../journal/routes/JournalRoutes'
export const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<div>Add whatever you want at / route here</div>}/>
      <Route path='/auth/*' element={<AuthRoutes/>}/>
      <Route path='/journal' element={<Outlet/>}>
        <Route index element={<JournalPage/>}/>
        <Route path='*' element={<JournalPage/>}/>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```